# How to use XSLT to find radom no. of levels of subfolder and rereive data

Tags: xslt

I am stuck here. can not think of a clever way to do this.Need to retrieve data under 'reporting:line'. 2 data needs to be retreived 'reporting:name' and 'reporting:ident'. 'reporting:line' is under the random numbers of sub-level of 'reporting:forder'. so they can be in the 100th sub-folder. so i need a kind of clever code to automatically find the correct level to retreive data.

essentially need to see following as result:

```
test2,-32
test3,1
test14,56
```

the below is the xml source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<reporting:root xmlns:reporting="TEST">

  <reporting:default0 reporting:type="TEST">
    <reporting:header>
      <reporting:property>TEST</reporting:property>     
    </reporting:header>
    <reporting:window reporting:Id="1" reporting:level="0" reporting:name="TEST" reporting:parentId="-1">
      <reporting:folder reporting:Id="2" reporting:level="1" reporting:name="name1" reporting:parentId="1">
 <reporting:name>test00</reporting:name>
        <reporting:ident>2</reporting:ident>
        <reporting:folder reporting:Id="3" reporting:level="2" reporting:name="name2" reporting:parentId="2">
   <reporting:name>test0</reporting:name>
          <reporting:ident>31</reporting:ident>
          <reporting:folder reporting:Id="4" reporting:level="3" reporting:name="name3" reporting:parentId="3">
            <reporting:name>test1</reporting:name>
            <reporting:ident>4</reporting:ident>
            <reporting:line reporting:Id="676" reporting:level="4" reporting:name="name4" reporting:parentId="4">
       <reporting:name>test2</reporting:name>
              <reporting:ident>-32</reporting:ident>
            </reporting:line>
            <reporting:line reporting:Id="661" reporting:level="4" reporting:name="name5" reporting:parentId="4">
              <reporting:name>test3</reporting:name>
              <reporting:ident>1</reporting:ident>
            </reporting:line>
          </reporting:folder>
          <reporting:folder reporting:Id="5" reporting:level="3" reporting:name="name6" reporting:parentId="3">
            <reporting:name>test4</reporting:name>
            <reporting:ident>5</reporting:ident>
            <reporting:folder reporting:Id="6" reporting:level="4" reporting:name="name7" reporting:parentId="5">
              <reporting:name>test5</reporting:name>
              <reporting:ident>6</reporting:ident>
              <reporting:folder reporting:Id="7" reporting:level="5" reporting:name="name8" reporting:parentId="6">
                <reporting:name>test6</reporting:name>
                <reporting:ident>7</reporting:ident>
                <reporting:folder reporting:Id="8" reporting:level="6" reporting:name="name9" reporting:parentId="7">
                  <reporting:name>test7</reporting:name>
                  <reporting:ident>8</reporting:ident>
                  <reporting:folder reporting:Id="9" reporting:level="7" reporting:name="name10" reporting:parentId="8">
                    <reporting:name>test8</reporting:name>
                    <reporting:ident>9</reporting:ident>
                  </reporting:folder>
                </reporting:folder>
              </reporting:folder>
            </reporting:folder>
          </reporting:folder>
        </reporting:folder>
      </reporting:folder>
      <reporting:folder reporting:Id="10" reporting:level="1" reporting:name="name11" reporting:parentId="1">
        <reporting:name>test10</reporting:name>
        <reporting:ident>10</reporting:ident>
        <reporting:folder reporting:Id="11" reporting:level="2" reporting:name="name12" reporting:parentId="10">
          <reporting:name>test11</reporting:name>
          <reporting:ident>11</reporting:ident>
          <reporting:folder reporting:Id="12" reporting:level="3" reporting:name="name13" reporting:parentId="11">
            <reporting:name>test12</reporting:name>
            <reporting:ident>12</reporting:ident>
            <reporting:folder reporting:Id="13" reporting:level="4" reporting:name="name14" reporting:parentId="12">
              <reporting:name>test13</reporting:name>
              <reporting:ident>13</reporting:ident>
              <reporting:line reporting:Id="160" reporting:level="5" reporting:name="name15" reporting:parentId="13">
                <reporting:name>test14</reporting:name>
                <reporting:ident>56</reporting:ident>
              </reporting:line>
            </reporting:folder>
          </reporting:folder>
        </reporting:folder>
      </reporting:folder>
    </reporting:window>
  </reporting:default0>

</reporting:root>
```

Comment: hmm how can i upload my xml source file? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:reporting="TEST">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="reporting:line">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(reporting:name, ' ', reporting:ident, '&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document, produces the wanted result**:

```
test2 -32
test3 1
test14 56
```

**Do note**:

1. **In XSLT one doesn't have to care about the actual depth of an element**. The power of XSLT pattern matching, combined with XSLT default processing allows us conveniently to provide only a simple match pattern for an `<xsl:template>`
2. **The default XSLT processing is** for every element to apply templates to its children and for every text node to output its content.
3. **We simply override the default XSLT processing by specifying a template matching every `reporting:line`** element in which we output exactly the string value of the wanted two children. **We also override the default XSLT processing for every text node** with a template that does nothing, so that no text nodes would be output.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, Thx a lot for your answer. I tried it and it worked like magic. I have more question now.I also need to report name and ident for level 1 and level 2 of reporting:folder in the file. and for each row of reporting:line it needs to report the correct top 2 level folder so the output will be something like:<\br> test

Comment: top level folder,2nd level folder,current level folder,name,ident
test00,test00,test00,test00,2
test00,test00,test0,test0,31
test00,test0,test1,test2,-32 
test00,test0,test1,test3,1
test10,test10,test10,test10,10
test10,test10,test11,test11,11 
test10,test11,test13,test14,56

Comment: tried add below but then reporting:line is ignored  : <xsl:template match="reporting:folio[./@reporting:level='1' ]"> <xsl:value-of select="concat('', ',','',',',../@reporting:name,',',reporting:instrumentCode,',',reporting:assetValue, '&#xA;')"/> </xsl:template> <xsl:template match="reporting:folio[./@reporting:level='2' ]"> <xsl:value-of select="concat('', ',','',',',../@reporting:name,',',reporting:instrumentCode,',',reporting:assetValue, '&#xA;')"/> </xsl:template>

Comment: not sure how can tell the code to go back to the top 1 and 2 folder to report them in the file. thanks a lot.

Comment: @ken: It would be good if you ask another question with your new requirements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304556/how-to-report-data-from-both-parent-and-child-levels-in-the-same-row-and-from-ra