# how to report data from both parent and child levels in the same row? and from random sublevel?

Tags: xslt

I need to report name and ident for level 1 and level 2 of `reporting:folder` in the file. and for each row of `reporting:line` it needs to report the correct top 2 level folder. Ideally it should report all top level folder details first then 2nd level folder details finally all `reporting:line` in any sublevel. So the output will be something like:

```
top level folder,2nd level folder,current level folder,name,ident  
test00,test00,test00,test00,2
test10,test10,test10,test10,10
test00,test00,test0,test0,31
test10,test10,test11,test11,11
test00,test0,test1,test2,-32 
test00,test0,test1,test3,1
test10,test11,test13,test14,56
```

not sure how can tell the code to go back from reporting:line to the level 1 and level 2 folder to report them in the file. thanks a lot.

xml file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?> 
<reporting:root xmlns:reporting="TEST"> 

  <reporting:default0 reporting:type="TEST"> 
    <reporting:header> 
      <reporting:property>TEST</reporting:property>      
    </reporting:header> 
    <reporting:window reporting:Id="1" reporting:level="0" reporting:name="TEST" reporting:parentId="-1"> 
      <reporting:folder reporting:Id="2" reporting:level="1" reporting:name="name1" reporting:parentId="1"> 
 <reporting:name>test00</reporting:name> 
        <reporting:ident>2</reporting:ident> 
        <reporting:folder reporting:Id="3" reporting:level="2" reporting:name="name2" reporting:parentId="2"> 
   <reporting:name>test0</reporting:name> 
          <reporting:ident>31</reporting:ident> 
          <reporting:folder reporting:Id="4" reporting:level="3" reporting:name="name3" reporting:parentId="3"> 
            <reporting:name>test1</reporting:name> 
            <reporting:ident>4</reporting:ident> 
            <reporting:line reporting:Id="676" reporting:level="4" reporting:name="name4" reporting:parentId="4"> 
       <reporting:name>test2</reporting:name> 
              <reporting:ident>-32</reporting:ident> 
            </reporting:line> 
            <reporting:line reporting:Id="661" reporting:level="4" reporting:name="name5" reporting:parentId="4"> 
              <reporting:name>test3</reporting:name> 
              <reporting:ident>1</reporting:ident> 
            </reporting:line> 
          </reporting:folder> 
          <reporting:folder reporting:Id="5" reporting:level="3" reporting:name="name6" reporting:parentId="3"> 
            <reporting:name>test4</reporting:name> 
            <reporting:ident>5</reporting:ident> 
            <reporting:folder reporting:Id="6" reporting:level="4" reporting:name="name7" reporting:parentId="5"> 
              <reporting:name>test5</reporting:name> 
              <reporting:ident>6</reporting:ident> 
              <reporting:folder reporting:Id="7" reporting:level="5" reporting:name="name8" reporting:parentId="6"> 
                <reporting:name>test6</reporting:name> 
                <reporting:ident>7</reporting:ident> 
                <reporting:folder reporting:Id="8" reporting:level="6" reporting:name="name9" reporting:parentId="7"> 
                  <reporting:name>test7</reporting:name> 
                  <reporting:ident>8</reporting:ident> 
                  <reporting:folder reporting:Id="9" reporting:level="7" reporting:name="name10" reporting:parentId="8"> 
                    <reporting:name>test8</reporting:name> 
                    <reporting:ident>9</reporting:ident> 
                  </reporting:folder> 
                </reporting:folder> 
              </reporting:folder> 
            </reporting:folder> 
          </reporting:folder> 
        </reporting:folder> 
      </reporting:folder> 
      <reporting:folder reporting:Id="10" reporting:level="1" reporting:name="name11" reporting:parentId="1"> 
        <reporting:name>test10</reporting:name> 
        <reporting:ident>10</reporting:ident> 
        <reporting:folder reporting:Id="11" reporting:level="2" reporting:name="name12" reporting:parentId="10"> 
          <reporting:name>test11</reporting:name> 
          <reporting:ident>11</reporting:ident> 
          <reporting:folder reporting:Id="12" reporting:level="3" reporting:name="name13" reporting:parentId="11"> 
            <reporting:name>test12</reporting:name> 
            <reporting:ident>12</reporting:ident> 
            <reporting:folder reporting:Id="13" reporting:level="4" reporting:name="name14" reporting:parentId="12"> 
              <reporting:name>test13</reporting:name> 
              <reporting:ident>13</reporting:ident> 
              <reporting:line reporting:Id="160" reporting:level="5" reporting:name="name15" reporting:parentId="13"> 
                <reporting:name>test14</reporting:name> 
                <reporting:ident>56</reporting:ident> 
              </reporting:line> 
            </reporting:folder> 
          </reporting:folder> 
        </reporting:folder> 
      </reporting:folder> 
    </reporting:window> 
  </reporting:default0> 

</reporting:root>
```

Comment: Please use `101010` button to format code block properly and ` for inline code pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:r="TEST">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="r:line|r:folder[@r:level=1 or @r:level=2]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor-or-self::r:folder
                                                          [last()]/r:name,
                                     ',',
                                     (ancestor-or-self::r:folder
                                        [position() >= last()-1])
                                                          [last()]/r:name,
                                     ',',
                                     ancestor-or-self::r:folder[1]/r:name,
                                     ',',
                                     r:name,
                                     ',',
                                     r:ident,
                                     '&#xA;')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
test00,test00,test00,test00,2
test00,test0,test0,test0,31
test00,test0,test1,test2,-32
test00,test0,test1,test3,1
test10,test10,test10,test10,10
test10,test11,test11,test11,11
test10,test11,test13,test14,56
```

**EDIT**: Better expression for penultimate ancestor (avoiding problems with posible `line` child of first level folder)

Comment: Alejandro, what can I say ? you rock!! that's exactly what i needed!. thx a million.

Comment: @ken: You are wellcome! Ask any time.